# Express authorizes all routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm debugging currently and I noticed that Express authorizes all routes that have parameters:

```
router.get(
  "/:type/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  getOne
);

router.get("/my-search/:term", (req, res) => res.json({ hi: "joe" }));

router.get("/search/:term", search);
```

Index file:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const users = require("./users");
const movies = require("./movies");

router.use("/auth", users);
router.use("/movies", movies);

module.exports = router;
```

And server/root file:

```
app.use("/api", routes);
```

If I remove `/:term` it returns json as expected.

Does Express caches the routes or something like that. Even the 'my-search' route requires token. Seems odd.

Comment: Try rearranging the order of your path handlers. i.e, put the first router.get after the 2nd and 3rd

Comment: Thank you. Now works as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. Posted an answer to complete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `route` in your first handler is dynamic, but very much matches the format of your route in your static routes defined later.

JS interprets :
`my-search` or `search` as a value for `:type`
and the `:term` you pass in as a value for `:id`.

Rearranging the route handlers fixes this as your more specific paths are at top, and dynamic paths are at bottom. So say, "search/ball" is matched by the first route handler rather than the last one.

```
router.get("/my-search/:term", (req, res) => res.json({ hi: "joe" }));

router.get("/search/:term", search);

router.get(
  "/:type/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  getOne
);
```